# Using intellisense and Vsvim

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsvim

I recently installed vsvim and was wondering how to do a few things.

When intellisense pops in and gives you a few options, 
Is there a way to choose them without using the arrow keys?

Kind of breaks the vim flow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use ALT, intellisense doesn't turn transparent!

Go to Tools, Options, Keyboard and edit these commands

Edit.LineUp : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
Edit.LineDown : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: I had given up on keeping the Vim flow with intellisense, but this was a really neat trick! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

In general no.  Once Intellisense is displayed VsVim essentially backs off and lets Visual Studio key handling take over.  Intellisense is one of the more important features of Visual Studio and VsVim attempts to integrate into that experience instead of taking it over.

But it's an area that's open to improvement if there is a good design around it.  Is there a particular way you would like to interact with it?

Comment: C-n to go down the list, C-p to go up basically. I kind of got it to work changing Vs bindings but the intellisense popup dissapears (becomes transparent) when I press Ctrl.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the keys in visual studio for intellisense like in Jason Mirks answer, but there are problems with various other popups, especially if you have things like resharper.   Quite a lot of these plugins don't respect the VS keybindings in their popups.  A good way to work around this is with an autohotkey script ( which does Caps Lock as the ESC key as well)

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
#IfWinActive .*Microsoft Visual Studio|ReSharper
<!k::Send {Up}
<!j::Send {Down}
Capslock::Esc
#IfWinActive
```